# Can I use computer cooling fins to build a dehumidifier?

Tags: humidity

I am trying with humidity sensors and want to build a simple humidity circuit myself, I already got a USB humidifier dissembled, now I need a dehumidifier.

Can I make a small DIY dehumidifier with old computer cooling fins and fans?

If it is a silly choice, what would you suggest that I can build one from common backyard scraps?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How are you going to chill the heat sinks below the dew point so the water can condense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@FiascoLabs brings up the key problem: The cooling fins and fan are good for cooling things that are above ambient temperature, but by themselves they can't cool below ambient temperature.

To dehumidify, you need to cool a surface below the dew point, which presumably is below ambient temperature. You will therefore need refrigeration, or a heat sink that is below the dew point (e.g. an ice bath).

You could pump ice water across the back of your cooling fins to get them below the dew point.

Comment: Exactly - The only time the dew point isn't lower than the ambient temperature is in foggy conditions.

Comment: I think you have answered the question. And further asking should gets me into electronics or physics, I am accepting this.